# What is a baby ling called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

[image: Ling]

Here is a ling. I was wondering what a baby ling would be called, as a a baby cod is called a cod-ling.

Answer (score 3):

The general term for baby fish is *fry*.

Comment: Yes but most fish have a specific term for their young, eg. Parr or smolt for salmon

Comment: There are an estimated 32 000 species of fish. I doubt the last comment is true.

Comment: The Ling have never been interviewed to see what specific term they have for their young, so we just don't know.

Comment: @Conneyfogle Also, using codling to refer to cod young might not be best practice, as it were, since codling is also used to refer to both juvenile and adule *Physiculus  nematopus*. [LarvalBase](http://www.larvalbase.org/) is a module of FishBase which has extensive information on the common and scientific names for fish in their mature, larval and juvenile stages.

Comment: Well, I've certainly learnt something today. And all from a one sentence answer to a prankish question.

Comment: @John Lawler: You just can't get hold of a linguaphone nowadays.

Comment: Why are you singLING my answer out for apalLING puns? I'm no longer wilLING to put up with this.